# HTML Simple DropDown list and Result

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple calculator with drop down list and JavaScript and I'm having trouble getting a result.

In JavaScript, I wrote the code to return `1411.21` if the setting value is Office. Otherwise it should return 500.
However, when I click calculate button, it doesn't do anything.

This is my HTML code.

```
<html>
<form method="post">
    <td>Setting : </td>
        <select name="Setting" id="Setting">
                <option value="Office">Office</option>
                <option value="HOPD">HOPD</option>
        </select>

<br/>

    <td>Facility : </td>
        <select name="Facility" id="Facility">
                <option value="100015">Mount Sinai, 123 Main Street, New York</option>
                <option value="100016">NYU Medical, 25 North Broadway, New York</option>
        </select>




    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Size : </td>
            <td><100sq cm</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Number of DFU patients :</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Patient co-pay % (based on wage adj.rate) :     </td>
            <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Co-Pay percent actuallly collected : </td>
            <td>75%</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" id="button" value="calculate" onclick="settingValue();">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Result :</td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="result" placeholder="result">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</br></br>


    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Medicare Payment Category</td>  <td>High</td>   <td>Low</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Medicare Payment</td> <td id="medicarepayment" style="display: none">
            <td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</html>
```

And here is the java script code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var mydata = {
            'Mount Sinai': ['100015','123 Main Street','New york'],
            'NYU Medical' : ['100016,'25 North Broadway','New York]
            }
    var firstNum;
    var secondNum;
    var settingValue;

    function settingValue(){
        settingValue=document.getElementById("Setting").value;
        document.getElementById("result").value=medicarePaymentCal(settingValue);

    }


    function medicarePaymentCal(value1){
        var result;
        if(value1=="Office"){
             return 1411.21;
        } else {
            return 500;
        }


    }

    function init() {
         var button=document.getElementById("button");
            button.onclick=medicarePaymentCal();
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get `document.getElementById("setting").value` but the actual ID is "Setting" as per

```
    <select name="Setting">
            <option value="Office">Office</option>
            <option value="HOPD">HOPD</option>
    </select>
```

Try changing the getElementById to `document.getElementById("Setting").value`

## EDIT

Ok, I made a JSFiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/dktoxtne/1/

Let me know if that works!  I don't remember all I changed, but I do remember you need to change the `name="Setting"` to `id="Setting"` and a few other things.

Comment: And additionally, the result element is declared readonly (though this is typo'd) and the element is never closed.

Comment: I changed it to document.getElementById("Setting").value and it still doesn't work..

Comment: As @Devsman suggested, the Result Input is typo'd, try changing that

Comment: I added a JSFiddle that works how I think you want it to work.  See my edit above

Answer (score 0):

```
function settingValue(){
                //settingValue=document.getElementById("setting").value;
                var e = document.getElementById("Setting");
                var settingValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                document.getElementById("result").value=medicarePaymentCal(settingValue);

            }
```